# Setting up SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, installation, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to set up a SQL Server for a development environment for a client. First I installed SQL Server 2008, I was able to connect to it from SQL Server Management Studio fine but when I tried to restore the `.bak` it said

> the database was backed up on a server running version 10.50.2789.
>   That version is incompatible with this server, which is running
>   version 10.00.5500.

After googleing I found I needed SQL Server 2008 R2 to match that version number, so I downloaded that from the Microsoft website and ran it. But I keep trying to set up a new server instance so I can restore the `.bak` but it's still creating another instance in SQL Server 2008 when I install it with version number 10.0.1600.

Can anyone suggest how I can set up a server running version 10.50.2789?

Thanks

Comment: What **instance name** are you giving your new 2008 R2 instance? Are you using that instance name when you connect to it??

Comment: If you want this database to live on your SQL Server 2008 instance, you can choose to **Generate Scripts...** for the source database to include both Schema and Data. Then you can simply run this script on the 2008 instance with no problem (provided the database doesn't utilize any 2008 R2 features).

Comment: Yes i'm specifying that specific instance

Comment: OK, so you can connect to the **correct**, new SQL Server 2008 R2 instance from SSMS? How do you tell that it's version "10.00.1600" ?

Comment: in sql management studio it tell sm ehte version number next to the instance name, then also when i try and restore the .bak file it says it's the wrong version number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had the wrong installer, no idea why as the original one I used had the exact same version name and file name only difference was file size. Not sure if it's right for anyone else but the file I need to install for Sql 2008 r2 was this one...

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26729

Hope it saves someone else the time it cost me thanks for all the great answers everyone

Answer (score 3):

Follow the link given.  [You will get details that which versions are compatible with the different edition of SQL Server. Hope it will help you.](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.in/)

Comment: Please add more content than just the link.  Link only answers are not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want SQL Server 2008 at all make sure you uninstall it first.  If you did not uninstall SQL Server 2008 prior to installing SQL Server2008 R2 then it's possible that you now have multiple instances of SQL Server running on your machine, and that you're connecting to the SQL Server 2008 instance.  Multiple instances on a single machine can be of varying versions of SQL Server.

Otherwise the only other explanation is that you're using the wrong installer.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I uninstalled everything and tried to install sql server r2 but when it gets to "select features" part it shows all previous sql instances (which i thoguht i just uninstalled) and shows this error message... "The version of SQL Server instance SERVER1 does not match the version expected by the SQL Server update. The installed SQL Server product version is 10.0.1600.22, and the expected SQL Server version is 10.50.1600.1." which is very confusing, as I read it in order to upgrade to sql r2 it needs to allready be r2, very confused